# Eilenberg-Moore Category

Tags: category-theory, monads

> We call an object $C\in\mathscr{C}$ is $T$-closed if $TC=C$.

> Suppose that $(T,\eta,\mu)$ is a monad on a poset category $\mathscr{C}$. Prove that the Eilenberg-Moore category $\mathscr{C}^T$ is isomorphic to the full subcategory of $\mathscr{C}$ spanned by the $T$-closed objects in $\mathscr{C}$.

(I think) I saw a more complicated version of this question on *Category Theory in Context*, which requires knowledge about the Kleisli category (which I don't have yet). I am basically lost at what to start with because I don't actually know what to do with the whole "full subcategory of $\mathscr{C}$ spanned by the $T$-closed objects in $\mathscr{C}$" and how to find a relation back to $\mathscr{C}^T$. Thank you in advance!

Comment: In general, if $S$ is a subset of $\operatorname{Ob}(\mathscr{C})$, then the full subcategory of $\mathscr{C}$ spanned by $S$ would simply be the category $\mathscr{C}'$ whose objects are $S$, and such that for $X, Y \in S$, $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathscr{C}'}(X, Y) = \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathscr{C}}(X, Y)$ and with identity morphisms and compositions similarly inherited from $\mathscr{C}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint 1: we already have an arrow $C \to TC$ since $T$ is a monad. Since $\mathcal{C}$ is a *poset* category, saying that $TC = C$ is just the same as saying that we have an arrow $TC \to C$.

Hint 2: since $\mathcal{C}$ is a poset category, all diagrams commute automatically, simplifying the definition of the Eilenberg-Moore category considerably.

---

**The below was written before I noticed you said *poset* category. Feel free to ignore this.**

I don't think this is true as stated. The double powerset monad on $\mathcal{Set}$ with $TX = P(P(X))$ has no $T$-closed objects. Even if we loosen $T$-closed to mean $TX \cong X$ (which may be what you meant to start with), the double powerset of $X$ has much larger cardinality than $X$. So the full subcategory of $\mathcal{Set}$ spanned by the $T$-closed objects is the empty subcategory.

On the other hand, the algebras for the double powerset monad [are the complete atomic boolean algebras.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94741/what-are-the-algebras-of-the-double-powerset-monad) The category of complete atomic boolean algebras is not empty, so it can't be isomorphic to the empty subcategory of $\mathcal{Set}$.

---

More generally, the Eilenberg-Moore category isn't necessarily equivalent to any full subcategory of $\mathcal{C}$. For example, the category of algebras for the free group monad are the groups, but the category of groups can't be equivalent to a full subcategory of $\mathcal{Set}$.

An easy way to see that is that the automorphism groups of objects are the same in any full subcategory (due to fullness). The automorphism groups of objects of $\mathcal{Set}$ are the symmetric groups. But the category of groups contains $\mathbb{Z}_5$, whose automorphism group is $\mathbb{Z}_4$, which isn't a symmetric group.