# Algebras for the continuation monad?

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, category-theory, monads

Given a monad $(T,\mu,\eta)$, a map $\alpha : TA\to A$ commuting with $\mu$ and $\eta$ is a $T$-algebra.

Given a set $D$, the continuation monad is given by the functor $C:X\mapsto D^{(D^X)}$ (see also [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/continuation+monad)). So an algebra for the continuation monad is a map $D^{(D^A)}\to A$. Interestingly, if we take $D=0$, this corresponds to the law of the excluded middle in logic: $\neg\neg A\to A$. This seems to imply that algebras for the continuation monad can't be constructed easily.

From the question [What are the algebras of the double powerset monad?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94741/what-are-the-algebras-of-the-double-powerset-monad), it seems that for $D=2$ we can take $X$ to be a complete boolean algebra, ie. $X=2^Y$:
$$f\mapsto(y\mapsto f(\eta_Y(y))) \quad:\quad 2^{(2^{(2^Y)})}\to2^Y.$$

There is also the free algebra
$$\mu_X:CCX\to CX$$

but both of these examples seem a bit contrived. For $D=0$ and $D=1$ there only seem to be trivial examples.

Are there simpler but nontrivial/interesting examples?

Comment: Well, if I'm not mistaken $D$ is an algebra via $\alpha : D^{(D^D)} \to D, f \mapsto f(\operatorname{id}_D)$.  And therefore, any product of $D$ (for example a function space $D^Y$) also has a canonical algebra structure.

Answer (score 2):

I asked this same question on zulip some time ago, and we concluded (well, Todd Trimble did teach us ;D) that if $D$ has at least two elements the category of algebras for the continuation monad is $Set^{op}$, or to put it more precisely, $[-,B] : Set^{op}\to Set$ is monadic (note that the continuation monad is the monad of the self-adjoint functor $[-,B]$).

Proof: check each condition in Beck's monadicity.

Comment: Could you include a link to the Zulip discussion?

Comment: [Here is a link](https://categorytheory.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/229199-learning.3A-questions/topic/algebras.20for.20the.20continuation.20monad/near/266126215) to the Zulip discussion.